# Получить path файла по Uri

Tags: android, uri, path

Как получить path файла по Uri?

Нашел вариант:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try { 
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Но, возвращает null (Андроид 5.0.2) Не могу разобраться что дальше делать.

Answer (score 0):

Это работает:

```
String path = fileUri.getPath();
textView.setText("Имя файла: " + path);
```